# We are able to delete the entries which were created during the transaction in cordapp. But how the immutability was achieved in Cordapp blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, corda

I created a sample cordapp and started the flow and made some transactions successfully. But I am able to delete the corresponding entries in nodes' database. As per the Blockchain principle we can not delete the entries in the chain. But how is this possible in Cordapp.
Please explain, correct me if my question is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In Corda, you are free to delete entries from your own node's database. However, you cannot delete entries from the databases of the other nodes you are transacting with.

This is the same as in Bitcoin. You can delete your local copy of a block, but you cannot delete the block from all the other full nodes.

The difference is in how widely the data is distributed. In Bitcoin, every transaction is distributed to everyone. In Corda, transactions are only distributed on a need-to-know basis.

Comment: Ok.., Then can we say our node's db or our chain become invalid in the network, or like how the further transactions get effected by this deletion. I could see deleting a entry is not stopping the new transactions. It seems some where we are missing the link. Isn't it so? @Joel

Comment: If you deleted a transaction, then tried to use one of the outputs of that transaction as an input to a future transaction, that would definitely cause issues. Please take a look at the discussion here: https://groups.io/g/corda-dev/topic/23176412.